# Auto-fill values in one content type to another content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have two content types email-feed and expenses.email-feed has one field long text. long text has also includes two fields which are company name and amount. and expenses content type has two fields company name and amount.

My question is: when I put the values in company name and amount (email-feed). these value automatically go in expenses fields (company name and amount).

Should I go with custom module or create rules for content types.

Answer (score 0):

use `Views Autocomplete Filters` module like this :

```
SELECT node_field_data.langcode AS node_field_data_langcode, node_field_data.created AS node_field_data_created, node_field_data.nid AS nid
FROM
{node_field_data} node_field_data
WHERE (node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type IN ('company'))
ORDER BY node_field_data_created DESC
```